# Alternative to M2Crypto's EVP in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, m2crypto

I'm trying desperately to upgrade an old project to Python 3 but one of our libraries that I wrote 3+ years ago uses M2Crypto which doesn't seem to be available under Py3k. It barely installs on Python 2 but that's something else altogether.

Anyway, we only use it to sign strings with its EVP module. Here's the extent of our M2Crypto usage:

```
from M2Crypto import EVP

def sign_string(message, priv_key_string):
    key = EVP.load_key_string(priv_key_string)
    key.reset_context(md='sha1')
    key.sign_init()
    key.sign_update(message)
    return key.sign_final()
```

Loading a key from a string, using SHA1 and signing a provided message. It seems really simple on the surface but I honestly have no idea what's going on. EVP is a black box to me.

Are there any other EVP libraries that work in Python 3? Or does anybody know the secret to getting M2Crypto working in Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, picking [another project's migration away from M2crypto to rsa](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/e0d267c593e063795ea0fb76741e2aeb1875808c),  apart, the above can be reduced down quite nicely:

```
def sign_string(message, priv_key_string):
    import rsa
    key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(priv_key_string.encode())
    return rsa.sign(message.encode(), key, 'SHA-1')
```

That's not to say that was all that needed doing. Python3's bytes/string separation screws around with a lot of stuff that seemingly wasn't an issue before. I'm sure it makes sense but it's a PITA when you've got to step through a long signing process in mature code to work out what you were talking about.